# How do I create an Internal Maven Repository with JBoss?

Tags: maven-2, jboss

Right now I have a JBoss application server and I want to setup an internal maven2 repository. I want the repository to be located on the application server. How would I go about doing this? Basically I want to host files on a JBoss application server similar to: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the repository to be located on the application server. How would I go about doing this?

In that case, your best option is to deploy a Repository Manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/). My preference goes to Nexus.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to deploy archiva on your JBOSS and create the archive through it:

http://archiva.apache.org/